# Pre-load and cache the next x images with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, caching, preload

I Have a need to dynamically preload and cache the next X images after the one currently being shown (Fullscreen Slideshow).
I have tried every way I've found so far, and the browser is still not caching.

*Note #1*: I don' t know if there's a relation, but the pics are at least 2 Mb each, on a good day.

**How am I preloading and Caching t he images**

Method **#1**:

```
$('<img/>').attr({
    src: list[url]
}).load(function() {
    alert("I have preloaded your next image.");
});
```

Method **#2**:

```
next_img = new Image()
next_img.src=list[url];
next_img.onload=function(){ alert("I have preloaded your next image."); }
```

Method **#3**:

```
    $('<img/>')[0].src = list[url];
```

What I see in my Browser Console is that they were indeed loaded, as I am also informed by the alert's.

But where I have my jQuery function, to change the 'src' of the image being displayed in fullscreen, the console shows the pictures being downloaded again, and doesn't mention cache, as I can also tell by the  3-4 secs of loading of the picture the method's above just loaded.

**Edit:**

I am experiencing the no caching in all the browsers.
All the images come from MaxCDN.

**Edit #2:**

They might be having problems with one of their peer locations.

Comment: Did you set up your web server correctly for caching ?

Comment: I'm hoping for a browser cache?The images come from a undisclosed CDN which tells the browser to cache them without expire.

Comment: I relalize that, but the web server sends a header with every image containing information about how long the file should be cached, and this is what the browser reads to figure that out.

Comment: Like I said, the images come from a undisclosed CDN that the client is paying, exterior to the webserver, and all the headers and etc are correctly set. If I open them directly it works.

Comment: What browser are you trying this in? If i'm not mistaken, for some reason in Chrome it caches them (but later does not load them from the cache, which makes no sense)

Comment: I really can't disclose any info of this client, the project is private. The CDN is MaxCDN.
But I am trying this on a empty page right now, where I have one img, with the first image from the list loaded when opening the website, and currently using the method #1 above to load the following from the list, which they all do and notify me correctly, but the browser doesn't load that image from cache, when I click my 'next' button, and simply replace the url attribute of the img in the page to the following url on the list. He just loads the entire image again. Trying in FF, happens in all.

Comment: It's mainly this: http://jsfiddle.net/5fpge/2/

Comment: I'm going to contact the cdn support anyway, something might be up for this region.

Comment: `at least 2 Mb each, on a good day.` thinking about the bad day :|

Answer (score 0):

How about you request and load the images as a child of a div element, and absolutely position that div from the visible screen area.

Eg:

```
JavaScript:
var arrImages = {}; 
var image = new Image();
var image.onload = function() {
    $('.imageContainerDiv').append(this);
    arrImages[this.src] = this;
}
image.src = imageURL;

Css:
.imageContainerDiv {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: -1024px;
    left: -1024px;
}
```

This way next time you refer to the image from arrImages, the image should get picked up from the browsers cache / memory as its already loaded on the page.

Comment: I have done that, not directly mentioned above, becaue that's exactly like the other methods.  Despite their look, the are already loaded onto the DOM.
The second you change the src of an image, he requests but not from cache.

Comment: have u tried using the same image object instead of changing the source?

Comment: I have thought of that, but I haven't tried it yet and perhaps that would work, but that would also force me to remake a considerably part of a very extensive fullscreen gallery module with a "hack".
Since what I wanted from the browser is for him to do his job and cache the image which comes specifically from a paying CDN. But I will try that as an alternative later on, since I can't quite for CDN support to fix this, if it's their problem.

Comment: The images coming from the cdn do not have an expires header set, if you are paying for their service, you can askthem to set the headers on the content they serve, and the browser should handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

What about having the images on top of each other with different z-index?

Like:

```
.image_top {position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:100;}
.image {position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:0;}
```

The image that is shown:

```
images[0].className  = "image_top";
```